# HTML enbedded in a Circuit conversation?

Tags: circuit-sdk

Possible for a Circuit bot to answer with a HTML form embedded in the conversation instead of the standar richt-text-box? I'm thinking in use cases such as quick HR surveys, technical forms to be filled out by on-field technicians...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the new forms feature allows for the SDK (e.g. a bot) to post a form that includes the standard elements such as input field, checkboxes, radio buttons, dropdown, buttons etc.

For more information see https://github.com/circuit/circuit-sdk/wiki/Forms.

There are also a couple of example apps using forms, e.g. https://github.com/circuit/trivia, https://github.com/circuit/survey-tracker or https://github.com/circuit/support-bot

Example:
[image]